# SQL: Using x and y coordinates to display line information, more details below

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database which contains data like this:

```
Connector_id | C_x | C_y | Line_id | L_x | L_y  
'C100'         2     3     'L100'   2     3  
'C200'         8     9     'L100'   8     9
```

The program is supposed to find out which connections are at the endpoints of a line by using the x and y coordinates and output the database like so:

```
line_id | endpoint_1 | endpoint_2   
'L100'   'C100'       'C200'
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I don't follow the logic by which you arrive at that output record.  Also, have you tried something yet (which, by itself, would probably have made the question easier to understand) ?

Comment: So row 1 and row 2 both have a line id (L100). The x and y coordinates of the two rows match up with the x and y coordinates of C100 and C200, this shows that C100 and C200 are at the endpoints of line L100. In the database, the data are stored separately, the line endpoints are in one table and the connector positions are in another table and I have done the necessary work to match endpoint to connector, which is what you see above. Now I need a table that shows which connectors are the endpoints of the line. Since C100 and C200 are at the endpoints of L100, you see the output above.

Comment: OK, but how do we know which of the two sets is the starting point and which is the ending point?  What if one pair has the greatest x value but the other pair has the greatest y value?

Comment: For the purpose of this program, the start point and end point do not matter. If C100 shows up first in the table then it is endpoint 1, if it shows up second it is endpoint 2.

Comment: Which column determines this ordering?

Comment: The ordering depends how the data were ordered in the original tables which held the line and connector data.

Comment: No, this won't fly.  Records in SQL tables have _no ordering_ implicitly. You need to tell us a column we can use to generate your output, or I'm afraid it can't be done.

Comment: I'm a little new to SQL, could you expand on what kind of column you need?

Comment: I gave you a query below.  Feel free to comment on it, and perhaps it gets you closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am offering the following query as a possible solution.  This assumes that the "lower" connector ID corresponds to the first endpoint and the "higher" connector ID to the second endpoint.

```
SELECT
    line_id,
    MIN(Connector_id) AS endpoint_1,
    MAX(Connector_id) AS endpoint_2
FROM
(
    -- your intermediate query/CTE
) t
GROUP BY line_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much